# Unable to create computed field with date_add in SQL

Tags: mysql

In my database, I have a table called 'fine', in that table I have three fields, issue_date, expiry_date and fine_amount. I want the expiry_date to be computed from the issue date. The expiry date should always have 20 days more than the issue_date, So I wrote the query as:

```
ALTER  TABLE fine ADD
expiry_date AS DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 20 DAY)
```

But there is a syntax error. I can't seem to find the solution.

Also I want the fine_amount to be 10 * (difference in days between current date and expiry date if current days exceeds expiry date). How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you looking to alter your current table to have a computed column, or create a new table altogether?

Comment: Altering the 'fee' table , but creating a new table wouldn't be much of a bother

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).  You can't implement the fine logic in a computed column because the formula is non deterministic.

Comment: what about the expiry date? Do you see a problem with my query for computed column

Comment: The expiry date could be a computed column, but I think you would have to recreate the table and copy the data over.  And again, the fine can't be computed.  I gave you the workaround I would probably use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't implement the fine logic using a computed column because the formula involves the current time which is non deterministic.  From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

> Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of the connected user. Examples of functions that fail this definition: CONNECTION_ID(), CURRENT_USER(), NOW().

So your best bet probably is to just compute values for these columns at the time you actually select.  For example:

```
SELECT issue_date,
       DATE_ADD(issue_date, INTERVAL 20 DAY) AS expiry_date,
       CASE WHEN NOW() > DATE_ADD(issue_date, INTERVAL 20 DAY)
            THEN 10*DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE_ADD(issue_date, INTERVAL 20 DAY))
            ELSE 0 END AS fine_amount
FROM fine
```